How to type hint Self on a Python Metaclass?
I have classes Gene and Genome that represent the biologic genes and genomes. I need to be able to write this code:
for being in Genome:
  ...

for gene in Gene:
  ...

The idea is to iterate through all possible combinations of a Gene (e.g. people with blood group A, can have that gene being AA, AO or OA) or through all possible combinations of a Genome (e.g. if a being has genes for eye colour, blood group, and rhesus antigens, the loop will generate all possible combinations of every gene).
Please note that the CLASS is iterable, NOT the instance of those classes.
So, to achieve that I created a metaclass like this (please let me know if this is the source of my problem! I did try something like @classmethod def __iter__(cls) but it is not allowed as __iter__ is hardcoded to the instance, not the class):
class Generable(type):
  # This overrides __iter__ being associated to the instance to being associated to the CLASS!
  def __iter__(self) -> Iterator: yield from self.iterator()
  def iterator(self) -> Iterator: ...

Then I can write the classes Gene and Genome
class Gene(metaclass=Generable)
  @classmethod
  def iterator(cls) -> Iterator[Self]:
    # Does its thingy to generate all possible Genes
    ...

class Genome(metaclass=Generable):
  @classmethod
  def iterator(cls) -> Iterator[Self]:
    # Does its thingy to generate all possible Genomes
    ...

This is where I have the problem with type hinting. On the metaclass Generable I could not find a way type hint __iter__ to return Iterator[Self] (like I did on Gene and Genome). Apparently, Self (mind the capital S) is not allowed on metaclass definitions.
This means that when I write for being in Genome:, actually being is of unknown type, because Generable.__iter__() returns Iterator[unknown].
I can write the metaclass like this:
class Generable(type):
  def __iter__(self) -> Iterator['Generable']: yield from self.iterator()
  def iterator(self) -> Iterator['Generable']: ...

But the metaclass Generable is just an empty shell to make classes Gene and Genome iterable themselves, so when I write for being in Genome:, being is now type hinted as Generable which is allowed far less than what a Genome would be. And since classes Gene and Genome are not related to each other, I don't have a "parent" class to serve as an umbrella. I really needed to declare the Generable.__iter__() to be returning Iterator[Self].
How can I achieve this?

Based on the code comment by @TrentonMcKinney:
First we make Generable a generic class:
class Generable[MySelf](type):
    def __iter__(cls) -> Iterator[MySelf]: yield from cls.iterator() 
    def iterator(cls) -> Iterator[MySelf]: ... 

Then we adapt Gene and Genome:
class Gene(metaclass=Generable['Gene']):
    ...
class Genome(metaclass=Generable['Genome']):
    ...

And now:
for person in Genome:
    ...

Makes person being of type Genome!

I actually think there is a bug on mypy. When I hover __iter__(cls) with my mouse, mypy says that cls is type Self@Generable meaning that cls would be an instance of the class Generable, when in fact, cls is the class Generable itself (therefore, it should be of the type type[Self@Generable])!
